# SQL sort column sum by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm very new to SQL

I've a table that looks like this :

```
Table1

User     Date      Amount
------- -------    ----------
David   5/1/2014    120
David   20/1/2014   300
James   13/1/2014   60
Albert  29/1/2014   300
David   9/2/2014    110
Albert  2/2/2014    90
```

How do you write an SQL command to produce a result like this  :

```
User    January  February
------  ---      ------
Albert  300      90
David   420      110
James   60       0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
`user`,
sum(case when month(`date`) = 1 then amount else 0 end) january,
sum(case when month(`date`)= 2 then amount else 0 end) february
from tbl
group by `user`
```

A quick explanation - we group by the user name to get the sum of amount per user, the sum function to calculate total amount and `case` to selectively include those records which match the requirements for that column i.e. January column should have sum of all records for January only, and so on.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69552/1)

Comment: Nice and simple query +1 from my side :)